# kivymd getting error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.uix.boxlayout'**

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

kivymd
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pTYD.png)
getting error when running kitchen_sink demo and otherwise as well when importing BoxLayout.

Error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.uix.boxlayout'**.

boxlayout.py file exists in kivymd.uix folder.

Answer (score 0):

`KivyMD` does not include `BoxLayout`
Use `from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout` instead..